# Как в unity сделать так, чтобы объект A двигался в сторону объекта B и при этом не проходил через другие объекты

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мы попробовали сделать это через rigidbody.AddForse(), но объект A начинал кружиться вокруг объекта B.

`gameObject.GetComponent< Rigidbody >().AddForce((ghost.transform.position - transform.position)*10f, ForceMode.Force);`

Где ghost это объект B.
[image: Это изображение того, что нам надо]

[image: ---]

Comment: А если у вас расстояние будет не очень большое, а вы потом вектор движения умножаете на **10**, то у вас объекта А перескочит объект B на такой скорости?

Comment: Если вы имеете ввиду, что объект Аза один кадр переместится за объект В, а в следующей на свое прежнее место, то нет. Поскольку мы используем AddFosre() объект будет перемещаться более менее плавно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот ссылка на документацию, тут подробно расписано, как использовать Lerp:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html

Именно этот оператор, как по мне больше всего подходит.